# Postgresql 9.2 DBLINK windows 7

Tags: postgresql

I have installed the PostgreSQL9.2 and I need to use DBLink after searching through the internet, it is stated that the dblinke should be found under PostgreSQL\9.2\share\contrib. In my case the contrib folder is empty. How can I install the DBlink in Windows?

Comment: Installed PostgreSQL 9.2 *from* *where*?

Comment: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows i Used the links here to install it. It is the 9.2.4

Comment: Weird ... that should install the contrib modules. Are they listed in StackBuilder if you run it?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by creating a folder dblink under the contrib folder and then I have copied the 3 files (dblink.control, dblink--1.0 and dblink--unpackaged--1.0) form share\extensions to the new folder share\contrib\dblink and after i run the CREATE EXTENSION dblink in each database that i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by creating a folder dblink under the contrib folder and then I have copied the 3 files (dblink.control, dblink--1.0 and dblink--unpackaged--1.0) form share\extensions to the new folder share\contrib\dblink and after i run the CREATE EXTENSION dblink in each database that i need.

Comment: That's extremely odd. If you don't mind it'd be nice if you could send your installer log (see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation) to pgsql-bugs@postgresql.org along with the other info listed there.

Comment: I will try to send the information as suggest from the link you have provided me. thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
select ST.Table_Name, ST.Column_Name, DV.Table_Name, DV.Column_Name, * from information_schema.Columns ST full outer join dblink('dbname=otherdatabase','select Table_Name, Column_Name from information_schema.Columns') DV(Table_Name text, Column_Name text) on ST.Table_Name = DV.Table_name and ST.Column_Name = DV.Column_Name where ST.Column_Name is null or DV.Column_Name is NULL
```

Comment: Please explain how this is an answer to the question.